# Is it possible to recover/archive some of the comments?

Tags: support, comment

This is about the comment area of [The continuity of $g\circ h$ and $h$, and $h$ surjective, imply the continuity of $g$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788970/the-continuity-of-g-circ-h-and-h-and-h-surjective-imply-the-continuity-o?noredirect=1#comment10183585_4788970)

As a not-very-obvious question, many lovely commenters leaves a lot of ideas and proof snippets in the comment area. However, they got (auto) deleted. All my notifications are deleted too.

Usually, the **comments are moved to chat**, and people can also read the comments if they want.

I wonder if we have an archive of comments for this question? Or if we can recover them in a chat?

Many thanks!

Comment: That thread contained a couple of comments which were flagged as unfriendly, a lot of comments responding to (parts of) those comments, several comments about resolved issues in the question post, more back-and-forth, and partial answers.  I did not think that it was possible to disentangle the "useful" comments from the rest, and purged the thread.  Keep in mind that this is *standard practice* across the SE network.  Comments are temporary, and you should not expect them to stick around.  If it is important enough to keep, take it out of the comments.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the comments were purged, but speaking from the point of view of someone who is visiting your (well-written) post to read the mathematical content, the first answer appears right below the question rather than below a string of potentially distracting comments, and I didn't feel like there was any missing information that may have been in the removed comments. The unfriendly comments and their responses created the problem. If there would have been no responses, then those unfriendly comments could have just been taken out without any problem.

Comment: Not all comments are temporary. Only the ones the moderators want to delete.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks a lot for you help yet I am a bit shocked. Why "many" comments were flagged as unfriendly? All comments were about mathematical concepts rather than a specific person. How could they be "unfriendly"?

Comment: High,   one option is to assume that any  thread of comments is in danger of being deleted. Thus, on a question of yours, take a screen capture of each item, say once  or twice a day. Save these to some file in your home computer.